# golang wasm:Remove the content of golang compilation wasm import wasi_snapshot_preview1

Tags: go, webassembly, wasi

When I use Golang to compile into wasm, `(import "wasi_snapshot_preview1" "fd_write" (func $runtime.fd_write (type 2)))` will be introduced, but the environment running wasm does not support the `wasi_snapshot_preview1` module. How to compile Remove the module `wasi_snapshot_preview1？`

the main.go:

```
package main
func main() {
    
}
```

build wasm cmd:

`GOOS=wasip1 GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm main.go`

the convert wasm to wat file:

```
 wasm2wat main.wasm -o main.wat
```

the wat file

```
(module
  (type (;0;) (func))
  (type (;1;) (func (param i32)))
  (type (;2;) (func (param i32 i32 i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (type (;3;) (func (param i32 i32)))
  (type (;4;) (func (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (type (;5;) (func (result i32)))
  (type (;6;) (func (param i32) (result i32)))
  (type (;7;) (func (param i32 i32 i32)))
  (type (;8;) (func (param i32 i32 i32 i32)))
  (import "wasi_snapshot_preview1" "fd_write" (func $runtime.fd_write (type 2))) //expcting don`t import 
.....)
```

I expect that the compiled wasm file does not contain the module `wasi_snapshot_preview1`

Comment: I also tried to use tinygo to compile, but the same problem still occurred.

the build cmd:  `tinygo build -o counter.wasm -target wasm ./main.go`

Comment: To me it seems like a bug that `tinygo`, which also has `target=wasi`, outputs the `"wasi_snapshot_preview1" "fd_write"` import. If you know it's not used, I would give it an empty import from the host. If you really want to remove it, look into `walrus` and `wasm-snip`